# Есть ли отличия между тесселяцией и триангуляцией?

Tags: графика

И при триангуляции и при тесселяции происходит разбиение объектов на полигоны. Чем они отличаются и для каких целей применяется каждая из них?

Comment: Это одно и то же. Нужны они для повышения реалистичности изображения низкополигональных объектов (происходит разбиение полигоной на части.).

Comment: Может быть есть какие то отличия в способах или методах повышения реалистичности между тесселяцией и триангуляцией?  Просто преподаватель дал задание объяснить в чем их отличие и для чего каждая из них применяется..

Comment: С помощью теселяции можно менять меш через карту высот.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тесселяция является более общей техникой. Поверхность разбивается на мелкие многоугольники, как вот в этом примере в средней строке:
[image: пример тесселяции]

Триангуляция разбивает строго на треугольники, где соседние граничат по общей стороне.
[image: пример триангуляции]
Так что триангуляция тоже тесселяция, а тесселяция с верхнего рисунка не триангуляция: и то и другое применяется для показа поверхностей.  Триангуляция применяется когда необходимо чтобы каждый кусочек лежал строго в одной плоскости. Треугольник всегда лежит в одной плоскости. Когда сеть разбивает поверхность, то кусочки с четырьмя и более вершинами не всегда плоские.